# How are piped processes presented in ps output?

Tags: bash, shell, process, pipe

I have a following very simple script which watches /tmp directory for new files and output of `inotifywait` is piped to `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/inotifywait -q -m /tmp --format %f | sed 's/a/b/'
```

If I check the output of `pstree` then I can see that both `inotifywait` and `sed` are indeed running:

```
  |-bash(20568)---test(8208)-+-inotifywait(8209)
  |                          `-sed(8210)
```

Now if I pipe the output of `inotifywait` to while loop instead of directly to `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/inotifywait -q -m /tmp --format %f | 
  while IFS= read -r file; do
    sed 's/a/b/' "$file"
  done
```

..then according to `pstree`:

```
    |-bash(20568)---test(8979)-+-inotifywait(8980)
    |                          `-test(8981)
```

..and `ps`:

```
$ ps -p 8981 -o command
COMMAND
/bin/bash ./test
$
```

..it is the shell which is started and not the external utility `sed`. Am I correct that this is simply because `while` is the `bash` shell builtin?

Comment: What happens when `inotifywait` outputs something, so that the `read` completes and `sed` starts?

Answer (score 1):

The relation of processes in a pipe mainly depends on the shell you use.

Modern shells make all simple processes (commands) in a pipe direct children of the main shell.

Older shells do this in a different implementation specific way.

Some shells run a while loop inside a sub-shell when the input is redirected, others do not.

`while` is not a shell builtin command but part of the shell syntax.

Conclusion: Do not try to analyse parent child relations in complex shell commands unless you are the author of that shell and like to check whether things work the way they are currently intended in this specific shell.